# ApacheDS admin user locked out

Tags: apacheds

Somehow (probably through neglect), my ApacheDS admin account has been locked out - whenever I try to bind I get the error:

```
 INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: password expired and max grace logins were used
```

I have been searching all morning for instructions on how to unlock ApacheDS accounts and all of the instructions require binding under the admin account...

Does anyone out there know how to unlock the admin account?

FYI: I have localhost access to the ApacheDS server.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process for fixing this issue is to stop the apacheds service, then remove the system partition:

```
rm -rf $INSTANCE_DIR/partitions/system
```

*Where `$INSTANCE_DIR` is the root directory of your instance*

Then restart apacheds.  The system directory will be rebuilt to the default settings including the admin user account.  So now, you can bind with the default password `secret`, and change it to whatever you like.

Note, that this will remove anything you added to the system partition as well, so if you customized that partition or added your own data there, you will need to restore that data from backup.